# How do I use zgrep to look for content in archived files matching a given filename pattern?

Tags: grep, zgrep

Suppose I have two tar.gz files

```
a1.tar.gz
a2.tar.gz
```

and each archive contains many files, including a file called

```
target.txt
```

How do I search for `BLAH` in `target.txt` in both of these archives using zgrep without searching all of the other files in each archive?

If I try

```
zgrep -a BLAH *.tar.gz
```

then that searches all files in each archive, and if I try

```
zgrep --include=target.txt -a BLAH *.tar.gz
```

then I get

```
zgrep: --include=target.txt: option not supported
```

Comment: as per manual, `These grep options will cause zgrep to terminate with an error code: (-[drRzZ]|--di*|--exc*|--inc*|--rec*|--nu*)` which explains the error you got.. not sure if there's an easy way around this, but may be use https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61461/how-to-extract-specific-files-from-tar-gz to first extract only `target.txt` from these archives and then use normal grep...